# Erro Invalid method::addStorageType(Array ? <block> (Magento)

Tags: magento

Estou desenvolvendo um módulo e quando eu faço a chamada na tag `<block>` dentro do `config.xml`quando acesso a página na loja afetada que vai receber o novo bloco customizado me aparece essse erro aqui: http://pastebin.com/qbRAGewV `(a:5:{i:0;s:101:"Invalid method Sc_StockMessages_Block_Messages::addStorageType(Array)`. Como proceder? grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi.... o nome `"messages"` é reservado do core.... alterei na chamada do XML da pasta layout o `"name"`